# How can I authorize a connection between two Gitlab and Freeipa containers (LDAP)?

Tags: docker, gitlab, ldap, single-sign-on, freeipa

here's my problem.
I have a **Freeipa LDAP (centos-8-stream-4.9.8)** instance and another **Gitlab (16.0.2-ee.0)** instance running locally in two **separate** containers.

These instances were launched via a **docker-compose**. No problem for these instances, both are accessible and work perfectly.

I'm trying to make an **SSO** connection with my Gitlab instance and the Freeipa server with **LDAP**.

On my native machine, the following command works:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://freeipa.packops.local -D "uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=packops,dc=local" -b "uid=user,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=packops,dc=local" -w YOURPASSWORD
```

and returns this result:

```
   # extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <uid=user,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=packops,dc=local> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# user, users, accounts, packops.local
dn: uid=user,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=packops,dc=local
givenName: user
sn: user
uid: user
cn: user user
displayName: user user
initials: uu
gecos: user user
krbPrincipalName: user@PACKOPS.LOCAL
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalperson
objectClass: inetorgperson
objectClass: inetuser
objectClass: posixaccount
objectClass: krbprincipalaux
objectClass: krbticketpolicyaux
objectClass: ipaobject
objectClass: ipasshuser
objectClass: ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys
objectClass: mepOriginEntry
objectClass: ipantuserattrs
loginShell: /bin/sh
homeDirectory: /home/user
mail: user@packops.local
krbCanonicalName: user@PACKOPS.LOCAL
ipaUniqueID: cee7019e-0f37-11ee-94dc-0242ac120002
uidNumber: 1615800003
gidNumber: 1615800003
krbPasswordExpiration: 20230620065805Z
krbLastPwdChange: 20230620065805Z
krbExtraData:: AAL9TZFkcm9vdC9hZG1pbkBQQUNLT1BTLkxPQ0FMAA==
mepManagedEntry: cn=user,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=packops,dc=local
ipaNTSecurityIdentifier: S-1-5-21-1133753079-3484878407-2653100528-1003
memberOf: cn=ipausers,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=packops,dc=local

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

However, when I connect to my Gitllab container and execute the same command, I get this result:

`ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1`)

Here's my Gitlab.rb config :

```
###! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**                         
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'                                 
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server                             
     label: 'LDAP'                                                                     
     host: 'freeipa.packops.local'                                                           
     port: 389                                                                                 
     uid: 'uid'                                                                
     bind_dn: 'uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=packops,dc=local'                
     password: 'YOURPASSWORD'                                                                            
     encryption: 'start_tls' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"                                         
     active_directory: false                                                              
     allow_username_or_email_login: false                                        
     base: 'cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=packops,dc=local'                           
     user_filter: ''                                                            
EOS
```

**How can I authorize the connection between my Freeipa container and Gitlab container?**

If you have any suggestions for solutions, I'd love to hear from you.

If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to ask me.